# Sending IOS .bin file to Cisco 3750 Catalyst Using TeraTerm (xmodem)

Tags: cisco, update, ios, cisco-catalyst

I want to Update my Cisco 3750 Catalyst IOS. I don't have a LAN Connection with the Switch,just Console Cable, so I'm using xmodem and Tera Term to send the .bin file to switch.

When I go to `Tera Term -> File -> Transfer -> xmodem -> send ->` and I choose my `.bin` file, after that I see this form:

[image]

It shows that Tera Term is sending your file but it stops right there! and nothing happens.

I even set the BAUD rate on Switch and Tera Term but it doesn't work. Is there a solution for it? Or any other way to send the .`bin` file to switch using Console Cable?

Comment: Sending an IOS image over a serial link could actually take a few days... You can set the baud rate to 115,000 on both the switch and terminal application, and then you must do a copy on the switch before sending from the terminal application.

Comment: I already Set the BAUD rate to 115,000 but that doesn't work
I write the copy command in ROMMON mode like this :
switch: copy xmodem: flash:
But doesn't work , (I/O Error)

Comment: Did you do the `copy` in `enable` mode command on the switch before sending?

Comment: I don't have that exactly what you have, but the copy command supports many protocols such as ftp, http, https, rcp, scp, xmodem, ymodem. It will take many hours through the serial port. If you are close enough to connect with a console cable, then you are close enough to connect with a network cable. Sending this through the network is the only reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not doing the `copy xmodem: flash:` command on the switch before trying to send the file. Also, make sure that you have a block with enough free space on the switch flash. You may need to do a `squeeze` if there is enough space, but not in a contiguous block.

You need to understand that, at the very least, this will take many hours, and it may take a few days, depending on the image size. The last time I saw someone try this, it predicted over 69 hours to complete.

Comment: 69 Hours??!!! God!
Is there any other way to send the bin file to switch? (except TFTP)

Comment: What is wrong with TFTP?